# iterate through a "map" where the value is "enum"

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, stl, enums

I have a map: `map<string, Operations>` where Operations is an enum

```
enum class Operations 
{
    div,
    mul,
    add,
    sub
 };
```

I filled the map like this:

```
myMap.insert( make_pair("add", Operations::add) );
myMap.insert( make_pair("sub", Operations::sub) );
myMap.insert( make_pair("div", Operations::div) );
myMap.insert( make_pair("mul", Operations::mul) );
```

How can I iterate through this map correctly? especially to get the second element?, (the value).
I am getting compilation error.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

enum class Operations
{
    add,
    sub,
    div,
    mul
};

template <class K, class V>
void displayMap ( map<K,V> &m )
{
    typename map<K,V>::iterator inx = m.begin();
    for ( ;inx != m.end(); ++inx )
    {
        cout << inx-> first << " " << inx->second << endl;
    }
}


int main ( )
{

    static map<string, Operations> myMap;

    myMap.insert( make_pair ("add", Operations::add) );
    myMap.insert( make_pair ("sub", Operations::sub) );
    myMap.insert( make_pair ("div", Operations::div) );
    myMap.insert( make_pair ("mul", Operations::mul) );

    displayMap (myMap);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('basic_ostream<char,
  std::__1::char_traits<char> >' and 'Operations')
        cout << inx-> first << " " << inx->second << endl;
```

Thanks in advance!. 
leo

Comment: Please show your compiler and the compilation command

Comment: What do you expect to be printed when you insert an `Operations` value into `cout`?

Comment: i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC)




clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -g -o fillMapEnum -Wall -Wextra fillMapEnum.cpp

Comment: There's no reason for `myMap` to be `static`.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with maps or iterations. Solve the problem of printing your enums first.

Comment: @KerrekSB I would like to add that the map can also be initialized as `myMap = { { "add", Operations::add }, ... };`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a scoped enumeration which does not allow implicit conversions to the underlying type. This is the whole point of C++11 adding them. You must explicitly cast them to the underlying type.

```
#include <type_traits>

cout << inx-> first 
     << " " 
     << static_cast<typename std::underlying_type<V>::type>(inx->second) 
     << endl;
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98343497c18728b4)

---

On the other hand, if you want to display something other than the enumerator value, you can create an `operator<<` overload to print whatever you want.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Operations op)
{
    switch(op)
    {
        case Operations::add:
            return os << '+';
        case Operations::sub:
            return os << '-';
        case Operations::div:
            return os << '/';
        case Operations::mul:
            return os << '*';
        default: throw std::runtime_error("illegal Operation");
    }
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/57f636e75a947bc1)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Operations` is not printable by `std::ostream` because there is no `operator<<` overload (and `Operations` is not implicitly convertible to its underlying type)

You can implement it as follows:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Operations op)
{
    switch (op)
    {
        case Operations::div: return os << "div";
        case Operations::mul: return os << "mul";
        case Operations::add: return os << "add";
        case Operations::sub: return os << "sub";
        // (omit default case to enable compiler warning for missing case)
    }
}
```

(Also note that this overload must be defined in the same namespace where `Operator` is defined.)